# Show Facebook Feeds in Cross Platform App Without Login

Tags: facebook, xamarin.forms

I'm new in mobile development so I started with Xamarin.Forms

I'm part of organization which wants me to develope an Telephone Directory App (which is ready) and include their Facebook Page in it so that events can be shown in app itself

I tried to search web for some sort of help came out with different options but none can be implemented because

1. Facebook Page is created by another member with his personal ID
2. Various post suggest to access public posts using APP ID, App Secret & access-tokens generated from https://developers.facebook.com/

How can I generate an access-tokens for and facebook page which is created by another user and include it in my app.

What are the settings which I should do in Facebook Developer Console so that anyone using my mobile app can easily view facebook page in app and go to browser if he/she taps any image or post so that he can login to facebook and post his comment or like the page etc...

Please Guide me.

Amit Saraf

**EDIT**

CBroe

> Yes, you would need a basic HTML document that contains the necessary code and embeds the FB JS SDK

Here is my HTML File

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=<AppID>";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-page" 
data-href="https://www.facebook.com/AkolaIndustriesAssociation" 
data-tabs="timeline" 
data-small-header="true" 
data-adapt-container-width="true" 
data-adapt-container-height="true"
data-hide-cover="false" 
data-show-facepile="true">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/AkolaIndustriesAssociation" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/AkolaIndustriesAssociation">Akola Industries Association</a></blockquote>
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But it is Not working
Where I'm wrong

**Edit**

CBroe

> Is this document called via http:// or https://? Otherwise the protocol-relative URL to the SDK can’t work of course, so you would need to add a protocol to the URL in the code. – CBroe 18 hours ago

**XAML Code**

```
<WebView x:Name="Browser" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000"
                        Navigating="webOnNavigating"
                        Navigated="webOnEndNavigating" />
```

**C# Code**

```
 Browser.Source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = "file:///android_asset/AIA.html" };
```

Comment: If you use an app or page acess token, then you need to make the API call on the server side, because those two types of token should never be exposed in client-side code. Other than that, you really only have the option of having users login to your app on the device, so that you can use their user access token.

Comment: Is there anything like RSS Feeds in Facebook (I read about in some old posts)? if yes can I use them in my App? & How?

Comment: No, that feature has been removed.

Comment: I tried WebView and that is working properly except that it also prompts for user login from time to time though it shows complete page without login in. Is this way of showing Facebook Page correct?

Comment: Yes, Facebook has started to nag users to login, even when they are viewing a public page, a while ago. I don’t think you can work around that. If the page is public, maybe the [Page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) could be an alternative - that can show a page’s events as well, and does not ask users to login.

Comment: OK I saw Page Plugin. for using it I would need to create an HTML Page and show that HTML Page in Web View. right? I saw the code & tried to create an Single Simple HTML page using Notepad. but did not succeed. can you Help me on it? (I have't work on any HTML page of Website so Please )

Comment: Yes, you would need a basic HTML document that contains the necessary code and embeds the FB JS SDK.

Comment: @CBroe please see edit (included HTML File) was unable to find FB JS SDK

Comment: Is this document called via `http://` or `https://`? Otherwise the protocol-relative URL to the SDK can’t work of course, so you would need to add a protocol to the URL in the code.

Comment: This file is added in Android Asset and is read in WebView Control of Xamarim.Forms Application via StreamReader

Comment: @CBroe Please See Edits

Comment: `Url = "file:///android_asset/AIA.html"` - so, not HTTP(S), so you need to modifiy the URL that is used to embed the SDK accordingly.

Comment: Done http://gsakola.comuf.com/AIA.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with help of CBroe (See Comments to my Question).

Here are steps if anybody needs

1. Create a Developer Account on Facebook using https://developers.facebook.com/
2. Create a Facebook App and Make it Public by visiting  -> App Review -> Make  Public
3. Visit Facebook Plugin Page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/
4. Enter the details and click Get Code. Here you will received Java SDK Code and Facebook Plugin Code.
5. Using these codes prepared a simple HTML File (Sample Code Placed in 1st Edit of my Question).
6. These file needs to be accessed using http:// or https:// protocol (see comments) for which you need to place these page on web server and then access it (here I used free web hosting provided by https://www.000webhost.com/)
7. Add a Webview to your Xamarin.Forms content page and set its source to the url of your webpage on server. (in my case it is  http://gsakola.comuf.com/AIA.html )

Done.

It works like a charm.

Thanks **CBroe** https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe for your great help.

Amit Saraf

Comment: I dont't know why but it is not working in Google Crome and in IE and Apps WebView it works like a charm